# Getting NullPointerException while accessing values from AsyncTask to Map Activity class

Tags: android, dictionary, android-asynctask

In my Map app in android.i am using `ShowTheatersTask` class to display the near theaters on map and on Tap of that theaters i have to show the directions.I am creating Obj of WebViewDemo in HelloItemizedOverlay class.while i am accessing global variable in `showDrections()`  which modified in ShowTheatersTask `doInBackground()` are showing null values.even `current_latitude`,`current_langitude` as `0.0` ,which are initialized in `onCreate()` which are global variables.please help why i am getting `NullPointerException`.here is the main part of the code.

Note:in `onTap(int index)` of `HelloItemizedOverlay` class i am creating obj

WebViewDemo.java

```
public class WebViewDemo extends MapActivity {
public double current_latitude, current_langitude;
public String lat = null, lng = null;
ShowTheatersTask showTheatersTask;
private LocationManager locationManager;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.....
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

        Location location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (location != null) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(WebViewDemo.this, "Please wait",
                    "Theaters are loading...", true);
            dialog.show();

            current_latitude = location.getLatitude();
            current_langitude = location.getLongitude();
.......
showTheatersTask = new ShowTheatersTask();
            showTheatersTask.execute(current_latitude, current_langitude);
}


class ShowTheatersTask extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, Void> {



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Double... params) {

            double latitude = params[0], langitude = params[1];

            try {
                httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();// Client
                postRequest = new HttpPost(..web service call..);
                response = httpClient.execute(postRequest); 
                           //Sure getting responne as JSOn object 
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jsonData.getString("name");
                    JSONObject locObject = jsonData.getJSONObject("geometry")
                            .getJSONObject("location");
                    lat = locObject.getString("lat");
                    lng = locObject.getString("lng");

                    point = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(lat) * 1E6),
                            (int) (Double.parseDouble(lng) * 1E6));

                    overlayitem = new MyOverLayItem(point, name,
                            jsonData.getString("vicinity"), null);
                    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
                    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

                }
                mapController.animateTo(point);
                mapView.postInvalidate();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
public void showDrections() {

        /*****************
         *Here values are coming null
         *****************/
        try {
            Log.d("current lat lng values", current_latitude+" "+current_langitude);
Log.d("lat lng values", lat+" "+lng);

}
```

HelloItemizedOverlay.java

```
 public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

       //some methods

        @Override
        protected boolean onTap(int index) {
             WebViewDemo.MyOverLayItem item = (WebViewDemo.MyOverLayItem) mOverlays
                    .get(index);
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
            dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Get directions", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    WebViewDemo demo=new WebViewDemo();
                    demo.showDrections();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: means..? In logcat i am getting null values.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are creating new object of an activity class in onClick() i.e. in HelloItemizedOverlay class's onTap()

```
WebViewDemo demo=new WebViewDemo();
demo.showDrections();
```

I know current_latitude and current_langitude is primitive data type it shouldn't be have null value and is not the reason of NullPointerException. Your logcat stack trace would help more.

But this is clear you dont have to create a new instance of Activity class i.e. WebViewDemo demo=new WebViewDemo();

Comment: because i am getting more than one theaters so when user clicks any theater i ve to show directins from that theater to current location. while i am trying convert lat,lng as Double i am getting Null exception this is what in logcat: current lat lng values(3655): 0.0 0.0 lat lng values(3655): null null java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser‌​.java:272) at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:317) at com.popcornapps.moviecorn.HelloItemizedOverlay$1.onClick(HelloItemizedOverlay.ja‌​va:58) –

Comment: k..is there any way to call showDrections() from HelloItemizedOverlay..since its not an activity i cannot call startActivity().

Comment: Yes you can call showDrections() method from HelloItemizedOverlay class. You are passing a WebViewDemo.this on instance creation of new HelloItemizedOverlay(theater, WebViewDemo.this); just preserve the this object in class member variable in constructor and use that object for calling showDirection();

Answer (score 0):

doInBackground isn't running on the UI thread, that's why you're getting exceptions. You have to update your map in onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute.

Comment: But after completing doInBackground() only i am calling showDrections() in Map activity class. i written @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onProgressUpdate(values);
   mapView.postInvalidate();
  } but still NUll exception

Comment: itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem); has to be there too.

Comment: while i am trying convert lat,lng as Double i am getting Null exception this is what in logcat:  current lat lng values(3655): 0.0 0.0
lat lng values(3655): null null 
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:272)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:317)
        at com.popcornapps.moviecorn.HelloItemizedOverlay$1.onClick(HelloItemizedOverlay.java:58)